# Accessing PDF file stored in a .jar

Tags: java, file, pdf, file-io, jar

I am creating a GUI and I was going to add a simple pdf file as help file.
I included it in the resources package and searching on this board I came up with the following code:

```
private void GuideActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    try {
        File myFile = new File(("Help.pdf"));
        if (!myFile.exists()) {
            // In JAR
            InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
                                .getResourceAsStream("resources/manual.pdf");
            // Copy file
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // no application registered for PDFs
    }
}
```

The problem is that now the pdf reader cannot access the file because it is already used by the java application.
Is there a way to solve it? Otherwise I will simply add the file to the dist and work out the resource path.

Comment: Have you tried ?   `InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/manual.pdf");`

Comment: Did at least the copying work?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works very well, check if in your source code you created the folder `resources` with the file `manual.pdf` within. Also when you create the `jar` check that these file are exported.